# How do I operate on sevaral arrays in one loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

I think it's a simple one

I have 8 arrays T03 and I want to check for some conditions in every one of them in a single loop. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
while(i<length(RRs)+1)
    if T03_i(2,4)>0 && RRs(1:2,i)<0
        RRs(1:2,i) = 0;
    end
    i=i+1;
end
```

As you see, I want to change elements in RRs array based on conditions in both RRs and T03_1/T03_2/T03_3/.../T03_8. Since T03_i doesn't work, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the T03_i arrays are of the same size. You can combine them in one 3D array like this:

```
T3D = cat(3,T03_1,T03_2,T03_3,T03_4,T03_5,T03_6,T03_7,T03_8)
```

Then

```
V_mn = squeeze(T3D(m,n,:));
```

will give you a vector of elements from m-th row and n-th column from all the T03_i arrays at once and you can loop through them like `V_mn(i)` (here `i` has the same meaning as in your `T03_i`).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need all of the `T03` arrays to be checked:

```
while(i<length(RRs)+1)
        if T03_1(2,4)>0 ...
            && T03_2(2,4)>0 ...
            && T03_3(2,4)>0 ...
            && T03_4(2,4)>0 ...
            && T03_5(2,4)>0 ...
            && T03_6(2,4)>0 ...
            && T03_7(2,4)>0 ...
            && T03_8(2,4)>0 ...
            && RRs(1:2,i)<0
                RRs(1:2,i) = 0;
        end
        i=i+1;
end
```

Comment: Actually, I thought of that (yet it would be || as a "or" condition), but I was thinking of sth else, since it is a common problem.

Comment: you would like to generate the code above? Or you'd like to iterate trough array names? Not sure I'm following...

Comment: I'd like through array names, but anandr came up with elegant back door solution already

Comment: yep, I like his solution too. :-)